# Access child boolean query matched terms in parent custom wrapper query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm writing custom lucene query which is basically a wrapper around boolean query with many should clauses.

I want to access this boolean query's matched terms, and then either filter out this document depending on external statistics on those terms or proceed with this document without affecting it boolean score.

I believe I need to create custom **scorer** which will use **two-phase iterator** which will use **boolean-query iterator** as approximation and then in match ***method*** I will be able somehow to either match terms or return false. However, I couldn't find how to access matched terms.

```
 @Override
 public Weight createWeight(IndexSearcher searcher, ScoreMode scoreMode, float boost) throws IOException {
       var internalScorer  = booleanQueryWeight.scorer(leafReaderContext);
       var approximationIterator = internalScorer.iterator();

       final TwoPhaseIterator iterator = new TwoPhaseIterator(approximationIterator) {
        @Override
        public boolean matches() throws IOException {
            ???
        }

        @Override
        public float matchCost() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return new ConstantScoreScorer(this, boost, scoreMode, iterator);
}
```